# The object in the Controller is not filled in when calling the POST method, it gives an error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am making a Spring MVC application, and when I fill out a table in JSP and click the `"save"` button, the data is not saved, and an `error` is generated:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL \[n/a\]; constraint \[null\];
```

here is the output I have on the console:

```
 Pass_in_trip \[key=null, trip=Trip \[trip_no=0, comp=Company \[id_comp=0, name=null\], plane=null, town_from=null, town_to=null, time_out=null, time_in=null, passInTrips=\[\]\], passenger=Passenger \[name=null, passengerId=0, passInTrips=\[\]\], place=6f, date=null\]
```

and at the input to the insert method, my object is empty, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Controller

```
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_Admin')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "insert", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String insertnewform(Pass_in_trip pass_in_trip, Model uiModel) {
      uiModel.addAttribute("trip",service.findallTrip());
      uiModel.addAttribute("passenger",service.findallPassenger());
        return "/pass_in_trip/insert";
    }
    
    
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_Admin')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insert(Pass_in_trip pass_in_trip, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel,
            HttpServletRequest httprervletrequest, RedirectAttributes redirectatributes) {
        System.out.println(pass_in_trip);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            uiModel.addAttribute("pass_in_trip", pass_in_trip);
            return "pass_in_trip/edit";
        }
        service.save(pass_in_trip);
    
        return "redirect:/pass_in_trip/";
    }
```

```
Insert.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pass_in_trip</title>
<style>
form fieldset {
    width: 40%;
}

form fieldset label {
    display: block;
    /*width : 50%;
        float :left;*/
}

form fieldset input, form fieldset select, form fieldset textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pass_in_trip</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
    <label>Flight:</label>

        <select name="trip">
        <c:forEach var="trip" items="${trip}">
        <option value="${trip}" label="№ ${trip.trip_no}  ${trip.town_from}  ${trip.town_to}"/>
                </c:forEach>                
                </select>
           
            </div>
            <div>

    <label>Passenger:</label> 
    <select name="passenger">
        <c:forEach var="passenger" items="${passenger}">
        <option value="${passenger}" label="${passenger.passengerId} ${passenger.name}">
            </c:forEach>
                </select>

            </div>

            <div>

    <label>Date: </label> 
    <input type="datetime" name="date" value="${pass_in_trip.date}">
            </div>
            <div>

    <label>Place:</label> 
 <input type="text" name="place" value="${pass_in_trip.place}">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </div>
        
        </fieldset>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
Pass_in_trip

@Entity
@Table (name="pass_in_trip")
public class Pass_in_trip implements Serializable  {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pass_in_trip [key=" + key + ", trip=" + trip + ", passenger=" + passenger + ", place=" + place
                + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }


    @EmbeddedId
    private KeysPass_in_trip key;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tripId")
    @JoinColumn(name="trip_no")
    Trip trip = new Trip();
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("psgId")
    @JoinColumn(name="id_psg")
    Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
    
    
    
    @Column(name="place")
    private String place;
    
    @Column(name="date")
    private Timestamp date;
    
//Getters and setters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My program lacked a Formatter for each composite type (Company,Passenger,Trip)
Formatter code

```
@Component(value="passengerFormatter")
public class PassengerFormatter implements Formatter<Passenger>{
    @Autowired
    AeroDAO service;
    
    
    public AeroDAO getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(AeroDAO service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Passenger passenger, Locale locale) {
        
        return String.valueOf(passenger.getPassengerId());
    }

    @Override
    public Passenger parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {  
        return service.findbyidpassenger(Integer.parseInt(text));
    }
}
```

don't forget to include them in servlet-context.xml

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatters">
        <set>
            <ref bean="tripFormatter" />
            <ref bean="passengerFormatter"></ref>
            <ref bean="companyFormatter" />
            <ref bean="timestempFormatter" />

        </set>
    </property>

</bean>
```